# Python for Data Analysis error: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, data-analysis

I am following along the examples of Python for Data Analysis and the first examples shows:

```
In [15]: path = 'ch02/usagov_bitly_data2012-03-16-1331923249.txt'
In [16]: open(path).readline()
Out[16]: '{ "a": "Mozilla\\/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit\\/535.11
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\\/17.0.963.78 Safari\\/535.11", "c": "US", "nk": 1,
"tz": "America\\/New_York", "gr": "MA", "g": "A6qOVH", "h": "wfLQtf", "l":
"orofrog", "al": "en-US,en;q=0.8", "hh": "1.usa.gov", "r":
"http:\\/\\/www.facebook.com\\/l\\/7AQEFzjSi\\/1.usa.gov\\/wfLQtf", "u":
"http:\\/\\/www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov\\/pubmed\\/22415991", "t": 1331923247, "hc":
1331822918, "cy": "Danvers", "ll": [ 42.576698, -70.954903 ] }\n'
```

After following these instructions I get:

```
In [21]: open(path).readline()
Out[21]: 'ï»¿{ "a": "Mozilla\\/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit\\/535.11
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\\/17.0.963.78 Safari\\/535.11", "c": "US", "nk": 1, "
tz": "America\\/New_York", "gr": "MA", "g": "A6qOVH", "h": "wfLQtf", "l": "orofr
og", "al": "en-US,en;q=0.8", "hh": "1.usa.gov", "r": "http:\\/\\/www.facebook.co
m\\/l\\/7AQEFzjSi\\/1.usa.gov\\/wfLQtf", "u": "http:\\/\\/www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov\\
/pubmed\\/22415991", "t": 1331923247, "hc": 1331822918, "cy": "Danvers", "ll": [
 42.576698, -70.954903 ] }\n'
```

The only difference from the book is the "ï»¿" part.

Later, when I try:

```
import json
path = 'ch02/usagov_bitly_data2012-03-16-1331923249.txt'
records = [json.loads(line) for line in open(path)]
```

... what I get is:

```
`In [22]: import json

In [23]: path = 'usagov_bitly_data2012-03-16-1331923249.txt'

In [24]: records = [json.loads(line) for line in open(path)]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-b1e0b494454a> in <module>()
----> 1 records = [json.loads(line) for line in open(path)]

<ipython-input-24-b1e0b494454a> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 records = [json.loads(line) for line in open(path)]

C:\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_
float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    317             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    318             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not
 kw):
--> 319         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    320     if cls is None:
    321         cls = JSONDecoder

C:\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    337
    338         """
--> 339         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    340         end = _w(s, end).end()
    341         if end != len(s):

C:\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    355             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    356         except StopIteration as err:
--> 357             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from
None
    358         return obj, end


JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`
```

Does any one know why I get this JSONDecodeError error?

Answer (score 0):

Sir, ï»¿, It is not JSON format, I think that you should remove anomaly text 'ï»¿' or try some online format JSON to be more clear.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
When I open the file as txt format, it does not show this anomaly so I am not able to remove it.